# How to prove that a DVR is not complete

Tags: commutative-algebra, valuation-theory

My question is inspired by a comment in [this topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/501363/is-mathbbcx-simeq-mathbbcx-x).

> How to prove that $R=\mathbb C[x]_{(x)}$ is not complete in the topology of its maximal ideal?

One knows that $R$ is a DVR, and its field of fractions is $\mathbb C(x)$. Maybe an idea could be to use the valuation associated to $R$, or better say, the norm induced by this valuation.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it is enough to show that there exist power series, which are not rational functions, i.e. cannot be written as quotients of polynomials. For if $P(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_ix^i$ is such a power series, then the sequence $P_n(x):=\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_ix^i$ is a Cauchy sequence in $R$, which doesn't converge in $R$.

Comment: It is enough to show that $1+x$ is a square in $\mathbb C[[x]]$ (the usual expansion $\sqrt{1+x}=1+x/2+\cdots$ is Cauchy for the $x$-adic topology), but not a square in $\mathbb C[x]_{(x)}$ (this is proven exactly as for $\sqrt{2}\notin \mathbb Q$.

Comment: @Cantlog Thanks for the comment! Actually this was the argument used by ding8191 in his answer to the question that inspired me. But I looked for a more conceptual answer without any reference to the completion of $R$.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice ding8191's answer. You want to show $R$ is not complete, so it is natural to exhibit a Cauchy sequence which doesn't converge. Another way would be to say $R$ is not Henselian: the polynomial $T^2-(1+x)$ is split modulo $x$, but it not split over $R$.